# How do I get a client's address from a WCF Service Application?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services

How can I get a client's address from a WCF Service Application? Also, is there an event raised when a client connects, possibly with address information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 3.0, this is quite hard; but was improved in 3.5 ([read Detect Client IP in WCF 3.5](http://keyvan.io/detect-client-ip-in-wcf-3-5)). I'm not aware of an event, though.

Answer (score 2):

Which address are you looking for? The IP address?

If so, I hope you're aware of the limitations on that - it won't be accurate if the client's on the other side of a NAT device or Internet proxy.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the limitations, but for my application, NATs and proxies will not be a problem. I was hoping for an IP address or even a Windows PC name.

Comment: Ok, only other thing to think about is this: if the network topology changes, will they consult you first, or will the "networking" people assume they can change the network without permission from the "programming" people? Because that's how it usually works, and how it's meant to work.

Comment: If the topology changes, it should be as simple as changing a config file or two, but in the end, this will always be running on a local network.

Comment: Not so. There are several kinds of networking device which could be placed between you and those machines, which would prevent you from seeing their IP addresses. Another thing is that any of those machines could change their IP address, or add a second network card. In general, Application-layer stuff like yours has no business depending on Network-layer entities like an IP address.

Answer (score 2):

If System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress isn't null, then it has the remote address. But that might be a proxy or load balancer (the case I have in our production environment).

Answer (score 1):

It would have been easier if the WCF host provides a way of getting the service requester IP - so that you can call that method to get the original requester.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like following `OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.To.Host`